# If inside while

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, inputstream, outputstream

**PROBLEM SOLVED:** I forgot to flush the `PrintWriter` in client.

I'm having an issue with this code. The output is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5.5 but it won't reach 6 or 5.75 and I can't figure out what's wrong. It's a client/server application using sockets.

Client:

```
System.out.println("1");
socket = new Socket("localhost", 1035);
System.out.println("2");
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
System.out.println("3");
pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
System.out.println("4");

pw.println("hello");
String message = null;
System.out.println("5");
boolean done = false;

while(!done) {
    System.out.println("5.5");
    if((message = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println("6");
        cardname.setText(message);
        done = true;
    }
    System.out.println("5.75");
}
System.out.println("7");
```

Server:

```
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String message = null;
            boolean done = false;
            try {
                System.out.println("5.25");
                while(!done) {
                    System.out.println("5.5");
                    if((message = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println("6");
                        String resp = handleRequest(message, sock.getInetAddress());
                        pw.println(resp);
                        pw.flush();
                        System.out.println("7");
                    }
                    System.out.println("5.75");
                }
                connDec();
            } catch(Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
        }
```

Comment: Its probably blocked on `br.readLine()`. Make sure data is available from the server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code probably blocks on the `readLine()` call. `readLine()` blocks until it detects a `\n` or EOF, so unless your socket connection is actually sending one of those terminations, its going to wait for one.

Comment: But if it does not detect anything it should return null and write 5.75 and try again.

Comment: @KevinFurmanski It doesn't print 5.75 because it never reaches there. Your code gets stuck at the readLine() call.